# How do I dynamically pass parameters to published PowerBI report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I aim to generate a dynamic report that presents data based on a specified parameter. To illustrate, I have clients table that is loaded from BigQuery using DirectQuery, and my objective is to exhibit data tailored to each individual client while excluding the remaining information. This customization will be achieved by passing the client_id as a parameter, which could be implemented as a URL parameter or through alternative options if available.

The report itself will be singular, with each client accessing distinct data depending on the client_id provided. The intention is to deploy the report to the web.

By publishing it to the web,I can utilize a single report with varying client_id inputs to offer diverse data sets corresponding to each client.

I am using the "publish to web" option because I want to integrate it into our system, so I thought I can publish it to the web and use the single report with different client_id to give different data based on the client_id.

**I am looking for any suggestion that enable me to be able to dynamically pass parameters, and use these parameters to show distinct data view for the published report**

I have tried using the parameters and it worked with me on the Power BI service not the web published version.

Comment: "Query string filtering doesn't work with Publish to web or Export to PDF" - as per documentation: [Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#embedding-scenarios)